# Data type for dominos board

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple console Dominos game. [6|6] max tile. (total 28) in C#.

Need help figuring out what's the best option for creating a gameboard.

I need to know what the tiles are at each end, also be able to add tiles at either end.

Stack won't work. Not sure about simple ArrayList.

Can't think of another suitable data type for this.

Or if there is another way of presenting it, please guide me.

My tile is currently

```
class Tile {
    public int End_One {get; set;}
    public int End_Two {get; set;}
}
```

And the set is just a List .

Comment: Multi-dimensional array. `int[,] arr=new int[3,3];` would create a 3x3 "board", change it to the right type (hint: Tile) and you're all set... you can iterate rows and columns using a simple `for` loop.

Comment: You probably would need orientation too right? At least, that's how i know domino's.

Comment: Yes, I would need the right orientation. I was thinking to maybe use a linked list and add validations for adding the new tiles.